# I'm trying to design for algebraic data types on Pie language(Racket). But I can't did on my knowledge

Tags: racket

```
#lang pie

(claim Option
  (-> U
      U))
(define Option
  (lambda (K)
    (-> K
        K)))

(claim None
  (Pi ((A U))
    (Option A)))
(define None
  (lambda (K)
    (lambda (x)
      x)))

(claim Some
  (Pi ((A U))
    (Option A)))
(define Some
  (lambda (K)
    (lambda (x)
      x)))
```

I can't declaration "None", and I can't be assured what i have declaration.
So, help me...
And I apologize for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot make `None`'s type be `Option` because Pie didn't provide data type or likely stuff. But Pie has `Either` type already, so rather than make new type, wrap on `Either` is possible:

```lisp
(claim Maybe
  (Pi ([T U]) U))
(define Maybe
  (lambda (T)
    (Either T Atom)))

(claim just
  (Pi ([T U] [t T])
    (Maybe T)))
(define just
  (lambda (T t)
    (left t)))

(claim nothing
  (Pi ([T U])
    (Maybe T)))
(define nothing
  (lambda (T)
    (right 'nothing)))

(the (Maybe Nat)
  (just Nat 1))
(the (Maybe Nat)
  (nothing Nat))
```